# Manual Failover in PostgreSQL without changing database connection string in services

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

our ADO.net application uses npgsql to connect to postgresql database. We have implemented a normal cluster of 2 servers(master and slave) as of now.

As we don't want to change the database connection string in the application during failover, Is there any other way except VIP to point the application to the new master server after failover?

We are using postgresql-9.6.

Comment: It seems pgPool [can do that](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-failover.html)

Comment: If you used anything else than .NET, it would be easy with the built-in multi-host connection strings available elsewhere.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you please share any link to do it using VIP